# Update variable and calculate inverse

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, callback

I havea an app where I have two tkEntry widgets. I am trying to enter data into the first and have it populate it's inverse into the second. However sometimes it is easier to input the data into the second and have the first calculated.
For example:
If EntryOne=20 then EntryTwo=0.05.
But if EntryTwo=0.2 then EntryOne=5.
I am have two callbacks that I am using to calc the inverses, but it seems only the first one fires.
Can I have only one callback?

```
import tkinter as tk


root= tk.Tk()
root.title('XXX')
X_var = tk.DoubleVar()
Y_var = tk.DoubleVar()

def cleardata(Box):
    Box.Delete(0,10)
    
def callback_X():
    if not Y_var.get()==0:
        X_var.set(1/Y_var.get())
        X_Ent['validate']='focusout'
        
    return True
            
def callback_Y():
    if not X_var.get()==0:
        Y_var.set(1/X_var.get())
        Y_Ent['validate']='focusout'
    return True

w=200
h=300
root.geometry(str(w)+"x"+str(h))
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = w, height = h)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


X_lbl=tk.Label(root, text='X').place(x=68.5-25,y=(h/3))
X_Ent = tk.Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=X_var, width=10, validate="focusout", validatecommand=None)
X_Ent['validatecommand']=callback_Y
X_Ent.place(x=68.5,y=(h/3))


Y_lbl=tk.Label(root, text='Y').place(x=68.5-25,y=(2*h/3))
Y_Ent = tk.Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=Y_var, width=10, validate="focusout", validatecommand=None)
Y_Ent['validatecommand']=callback_X
Y_Ent.place(x=68.5,y=(2*h/3))

#def main():
root.mainloop()
```

Mon

Comment: Hmmm, i suppose you could `trace()` method of `DoubleVar()`

Comment: What your trying to achieve is not conveyed properly, please elaborate.

Comment: please fix your code. The way it is it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Wrote post on mobile apologies. But the only difference I see is the return true error, and defining the variables before the callback. I will look at it tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all the code you posted here doesn't work for many reasons, but after fixing this errors I found that the reason your callback functions are not properly working is that the method sent to `validatecommand` must return True or False. I've done this and worked for me:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
X_var=tk.DoubleVar(value=1)
Y_var=tk.DoubleVar(value=1)

def callback_X():
    if not Y_var.get()==0:
        X_var.set(1/Y_var.get())
        X_entry['validate']='focusout'
    return True

def callback_Y():
    if not X_var==0:
        Y_var.set(1/X_var.get())
        Y_entry['validate']='focusout'
    return True

X_entry=tk.Entry(root, textvariable=X_var, validate='focusout',validatecommand=None)
Y_entry=tk.Entry(root, textvariable=Y_var, validate='focusout',validatecommand=None)
X_entry['validatecommand']=callback_Y
Y_entry['validatecommand']=callback_X

X_entry.pack()
Y_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Made the following corrections, however when initially ran: enter value into X and Y updates, enter value into Y and X updates. From this point on only entering values into Y will update X.

Comment: Sorry, this was happening because after setting the `X_var` with `X_var.set()` the `Entry` associated with this variable loose the validation. I edited my code to reset the entry validation. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you. Works as needed.

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem might be that in the first function you defined the "D" in "Def" was capitalized when it shouldn't be.

Comment: If that was the case, the code wouldnt run at all, it would give a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Its probably a mistake while copy pasting the code.